# get element names from xml

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml

```
<MMDEF>
    <elem1  MmDefault="1" Se="1.xml"/>
    <elem2  MmDefault="2" Se="2.xml"/>
    <elem3  MmDefault="3" Se="1.xml"/>
    <elem4  MmDefault="3" Se="2.xml"/>
    <elem5  MmDefault="5" Se="2.xml"/>
    <elem6  MmDefault="7" Se="1.xml"/>
</MMDEF>
```

How can I get an iterable list of all elements elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4, elem5 and elem6 with their attributes included.

Have in mind that elem1, elem2 and etc can be completely random string so I can not use getElementsByTagName() in order to get their attributes

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to use [**lxml**](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html), which can be easily installed using command `easy_install lxml` on windows:

```
In [258]: x='''
     ...: <MMDEF>
     ...:     <elem1  MmDefault="1" Se="1.xml"/>
     ...:     <elem2  MmDefault="2" Se="2.xml"/>
     ...:     <elem3  MmDefault="3" Se="1.xml"/>
     ...:     <elem4  MmDefault="3" Se="2.xml"/>
     ...:     <elem5  MmDefault="5" Se="2.xml"/>
     ...:     <elem6  MmDefault="7" Se="1.xml"/>
     ...: </MMDEF>
     ...: '''

In [265]: from lxml import etree
     ...: rt=etree.fromstring(x)
     ...: for child in rt:
     ...:     print child.tag, child.attrib
elem1 {'MmDefault': '1', 'Se': '1.xml'}
elem2 {'MmDefault': '2', 'Se': '2.xml'}
elem3 {'MmDefault': '3', 'Se': '1.xml'}
elem4 {'MmDefault': '3', 'Se': '2.xml'}
elem5 {'MmDefault': '5', 'Se': '2.xml'}
elem6 {'MmDefault': '7', 'Se': '1.xml'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys. I used ElementTree since I already used it for parsing different parts of this xml. But I tried lxml and it seems ok as well

Comment: @user3346525 `lxml.etree` is [compatible](http://lxml.de/1.3/compatibility.html) with ElementTree, and it's [performance is better](http://lxml.de/performance.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

filePath = r'path/to/file'
root = ET.parse(filePath).getroot()

for child in root:
  print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```